# What is this microphone connector?

Tags: sound-design, microphone, audio-recording, recording

[image: Connector]
It's from a 70's Italian mic (UMC 7103), a unidirectional condenser microphone. I need to substitute the original jack cable, with a XLR, but i don't know what is this connector (it screws on the mic)
[image]

Comment: post a pic of the other side of the smaller part

Comment: @Daniel there you go

Comment: you need an adapter with a 1/4" female on one side and an XLR male on the other end.

Comment: just checked Ebay, there are a ton of them on there

Comment: so basically the adapter will let you plug in the 1.4" from your italian microphone and then you will be able to plug that entire unit into an xlr input

Comment: The point is, if this cable gets damaged, i need a new one

Comment: Can't help you there my man. Seems like a very old model. Good luck though.

Answer (score 3):

Looks very much like a vintage Switchcraft 2501 connector. Note that those were typically used for vintage high-impedance unbalanced microphones. So even if you had a cable with that connector on one end and XLR on the other, it would likely NOT be suitable for a modern low-impedance balanced connection (as you get with typical XLR mic inputs).

Ref: http://www.switchcraft.com/productsummary.aspx?Parent=810

Ref: http://www.angela.com/microphoneconnectorswitchcraftoldstylescrew-on.aspx